# ext3 mount options differ from linux kernel doc

Tags: linux, ext3

I'm playing in my server lab with ext3 filesystem mount options, looking the kernel doc

```
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext3.txt
```

I'm using redhat 5.8, if try to mount the fs in this way

```
mount -o noload /dev/vgmirror/lvmirror /mnt/
mount -o norecovery /dev/vgmirror/lvmirror /mnt/
mount -o journal=noload /dev/vgmirror/lvmirror /mnt/
mount -o journal=norecovery /dev/vgmirror/lvmirror /mnt/
```

Every above commands fails with error

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/vgmirror/lvmirror,
missing codepage or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so
```

This mount options was removed on redhat? or the kernel doc is deprecated? or i'm using the wrong commands?

Answer (score 0):

The man-page you are linking to refers to the latest version of the linux kernel, while you are on Red Hat 5.8 which uses a quite older kernel.

You are better out using the online documentation on the server.

Use the following command on the server and use this as your reference instead.

```
man 8 mount
```

Comment: Thanks, i found the mount options using man 8 mount, i will try to do the same commans in fedora 18 and i will let you know, maybe the problem is the man pages are updated, but redhat are using an old kernel

Comment: Just remember that the mount options might be different in Fedora 18 so you should read the manual page on that system as well. The real problem is that you did not read the correct manual page for the correct system.

Comment: using the man 8 mount, i just found norecovery option in the xfs filesystem mount options session, for ext3 nothing found

Comment: Why would you do anything on Fedora 18, which has reached end of life?

Comment: @c4f4t0r Then it is probably not available for `ext3` on your system.